# Is there any way for php to highlight the difference between two strings?

Tags: php

I've got a table which outputs two mySQL records, one original and one which has been edited and flagged for approval/disapproval by the admin. I want to change the column color to highlight rows which have been edited.

The color highlight on changed rows works for all rows except "SalaryFrom" and "Email", for some reason they are always highlighted as different even when the values appear to be completely identical.

Is there any function in PHP which highlights the difference between two strings so I can figure out where the difference is?

Here's my code for one row:

```
<tr>
     <?php 
      if (htmlval($cand['salaryfrom'])!==htmlval($flaggedcand['salaryfrom']))
      {
           $tcolor="#000000";
      }
      else 
      {
           $tcolor="#D3D5E8";
      } 
      ?>

      <td bgcolor=<?php echo $tcolor ;?>><b>Salary from</b></td>
     <td><?php htmlout($flaggedcand['salaryfrom']." "); ?></td>
</tr>


function htmlval($text)
{           
    return html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES);
}
```

Comment: "diff" is the term you're looking for, and I seem to be able to find [a few different implementations](https://www.google.com/search?q=php+diff+library&oq=php+diff+library)

Answer (score 0):

Use this

```
<?php 
    if ( $cand['salaryfrom'] != $flaggedcand['salaryfrom'] ) $tcolor ="#000000";
    else $tcolor="#D3D5E8"; 
?>

<td style="background: <?php echo $tcolor; ?>;"><b>Salary from</b></td>
<td><?php echo $flaggedcand['salaryfrom'] ." "; ?></td>
```

Comment: What is the difference here? Note, I need th htmlval function to handle special characters on one or the other.

Comment: difference is !== versus != There should be no difference in this scenario, actually, it is recommanded to use user2721465 version. Always prefer using !== rather than != when comparing two strings together.

Comment: Can you tell me? Why prefer !== than != ?

Comment: Sorry for my late answer Khrisna. I give you an example : $something = 0; if ('password123' != $something) echo "true"; else echo "false"; // returns "false" but !== always gives expected result

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons why your strings may look the same but they aren't for real. Example: Maybe you need to trim heading and trailing space like this :

```
function htmlval($text)
{           
    return trim(html_entity_decode($text, ENT_QUOTES));
}
```

There are a couple of classes, lib, or self-made function to highlight two strings differences (not in core php) but in your case it might be just enought to output explicitly string 1 and then string 2 so that you can spot the differences by yourself like this :

```
<tr>
     <?php 
      if (htmlval($cand['salaryfrom'])!==htmlval($flaggedcand['salaryfrom']))
      {
           $tcolor="#000000";
           ob_start();
           var_dump(htmlval($cand['salaryfrom']));
           echo " is not equal to ";
           var_dump(htmlval($flaggedcand['salaryfrom']));
           $out = ob_get_clean();
      }
      else 
      {
           $tcolor="#D3D5E8";
           $out = $flaggedcand['salaryfrom'];
      } 
      ?>

      <td bgcolor=<?php echo $tcolor ;?>><b>Salary from</b></td>
     <td><?php htmlout($out." "); ?></td>
</tr>
```